# Hypothesis Testing of categorical variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

**CONTEXT**

- Suppose i collected data sets from a survey over google form, my sample is consisting of 32 row with the age/sex/major of the person who filled the survey, they a multiple choice answer for each question with the degree of satisfaction example (my question is 1+1=? a) 1 , .. e) 5 each one with a degree of satisfaction from "totally disagree" to "totally agree", my study object is determining factors influencing employement rates, here is my conceptual model :
  [image]

**Questions:**
3) Also can someone explain to me how to build the matrix of correlation or is it called independence, also the tests of associations, and how can i build the regression model for my statistic study?

4. so the answers to the questions in the survey are considered qualitative entities thus we apply chi² test, but after we did the codification according each degree of satisfaction to the option selected, does that make the entity quantitative?
5. Okey regardless of what type of variable im testing normality for, does the p-value of the test the one telling me if this is the best/correct choice according to the population?

Comment: Please do not duplicate your question. The original question was closed for a reason...you have many questions rolled into one post, which can be edited to be just one primary question. You are far more likely to get answers if you have a post which has a singular question that can be solved with a straightforward answer. If a question is closed, you can edit it to have it reopened.

Comment: It's not a duplicate but rather the OP has split 5 questions across 2 threads (to get around the "lack of focus" closure?) It would be more productive to ask/edit one initial, succinct and well formulated question. Once that has been answered, write a follow-up question (if still unclear).